# How to get notified when Xamarin Native Android app goes to sleep or is terminated?

Tags: xamarin.android

How to get notified when Xamarin Native Android app goes to sleep or is terminated?

When searching, I only found an answer for Xamarin.Forms where the `Application` object allows to override `OnSleep`.

The background of this question is that I want to save settings when the app either goes to background or is terminated.

Comment: I have updated my answer you can take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the `OnSleep` method of Xamarin Forms the `OnPause` method is called in Android Native when the app goes into the background.

You can override `OnPause` in both an `Activity` and a `Fragment` something like this:

```
protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        // Add your code here
    }
```

**Update**

You can do the same on application level by adding the Android Application class :

Add a new C# class file in your project called `MainApplication.cs`.

Then add the Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks interface where you can find the activity paused method with the activity context in which it was paused so you can add it and do the needful.

```
 #if DEBUG
 [Application(Debuggable = true)]
 #else
 [Application(Debuggable = false)]
 #endif
  public class MainApplication : Application , Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
{
     public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer)
    : base(handle, transer)
    {
    }

  public void OnActivityPaused(Android.App.Activity activity)
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        // Add some code
    }

  public override void OnTerminate()
    {
        base.OnTerminate();
        UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }
 }
```

Comment: But this is per activity. So I would need to extend AppCompatActivity an override OnPause there. Isn't there anything application wide?

Comment: Well then you can use the Application class then wait i will update it in a minute

Comment: This was my first intent. But it seems there is no OnPause method. I'm using this class: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.Application/

Comment: You must have not added the lifecycle callbacks kindly take a look again

Comment: I can only check tonight when I have access to the code again. It looks promising as I don’t use the application lifecycle callbacks yet.

Comment: Okay take a look on whether or not this works and do let me know if it does!!